# Apache : Illegal override option FileInfo

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have installed a new Ubuntu 12.04 Server and setup Apache and MySQL.

I am just trying to replicate what I have in my current server and came across one single problem. -> FileInfo

Within these two files below:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

I need to add some overrides for the apache server.

Original:

```
<Directory /var/www/MySite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

New:

```
<Directory /var/www/MySite>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride FileInfo, Indexes
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have installed the following mods for Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^ -y
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common apache2-utils openssl openssl-blacklist openssl-blacklist-extra -y
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl -y
sudo apt-get install php5-tidy -y
sudo apt-get install php5-gd -y
sudo apt-get install php-apc -y
sudo apt-get install memcached -y
sudo apt-get install php5-memcache -y
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod headers 
sudo a2enmod expires 
sudo a2enmod php5
```

So When I do a restart with AllowOverride None, its all ok.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

 * Restarting web server apache2  ... waiting        [OK]
```

But as soon as I change the AllowOverride to FileInfo, Indexes

```
Syntax error on line 11 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Illegal override option FileInfo,
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

I can't see anything unusual in the error.log

```
[Wed Jun 06 08:23:51 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Jun 06 08:23:52 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `mySite.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Jun 06 08:23:52 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `mySite.com' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Jun 06 08:23:52 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.1 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I get that warning because its a test server, nonetheless I get the same warning with AllowOverride None and yet it restarts the Apache server correctly. Therefore this warning should be harmless.

Have I missed something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no commas in the list of overrides.  It should be

```
AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes
```